# How to check all Case startdate and updated case with high duration from startdate

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger, business-logic

I have requirement where on new case insertion need to check AccountId and all associated cases with that account.
Then 
need to compare startdate of all cases and whichever is earlier need to calculate duration from today.

```
A1-->c1   --------->  2/2/2020
A1-->c2   --------->  12/2/2020
A1-->c3   --------->  22/2/2020
A1-->c4   --------->  2/3/2020
```

Then need to calculate older date which is in above example 2/2/2020 and stamp duration from today in current case which is getting inserted.

I have written logic,but not working as expected .Please suggest

```
 public static void newCase(List<case> newCaseList){
    set<id> accIds = new set<id>();
    for(case c:newCaseList){
        accIds.add(c.accountid);
    }
   list<account> accList = new list<account>([select id from account where id in:accIds]);

    map<id,id> casemap = new map<id,id>();
    list<case> caseList = new list<case>([select id,AccountId,start_date__c,status from case where 
     accountid in:accIds]);
  list<case> updateCase =new list<case>();
    for(case c:caseList){
    casemap.put(c.accountid,c.id);  
    }

    for(account ac:accList) {
    for(case c:caseList){
        if(casemap.containsKey(ac.id)){
           date todays=system.today();
            date st = c.start_date__c;

            if(i !=null){
            if(c.start_date__c!=null) {                      
            integer i =todays.daysBetween(st);           
            integer j=i;
             j=i;
            }
            if(j!=NULL){
            c.Duration__c =j;
            updateCase.add(c);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
update updateCase ;
}
```

}

Comment: Are you trying to stamp the duration since the first case was raised in that account in a fields on all the cases i.e if a first case was raised 90 days back then you stamp 90 on all cases under that account?

Comment: I updated my question with example

Comment: A1-->c1   --------->  2/2/2020
A1-->c2   --------->  12/2/2020
A1-->c3   --------->  22/2/2020
A1-->c4   --------->  2/3/2020

Then need to calculate older date which is in above example 2/2/2020 and stamp duration from today in current case which is getting inserted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I suggest that you start with the approach of getting the oldest case for each account right from the DB rather than having that logic your selves because I do not see that calculations in your code.

The below code will give you an idea of how to proceed and you can fit this in your code.

```
Set<Id> accIds = new Set<Id>();
for (Case c : newCaseList) {
    accIds.add(c.AccountId);
}

// Get the accounts with the oldest case each

Map<Id, Account> accounts = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, CreatedDate, Status FROM Cases ORDER BY Start_Date__c ASC LIMIT 1) FROM Account WHERE Id IN:accIds]);

for (Case c : newCaseList) {
    List<Case> casesForThisAccount = accounts.get(c.AccountId).Cases;
    if (casesForThisAccount != null && !casesForThisAccount.isEmpty()) {
        // Add proper null checks here. 
        c.Duration__c = casesForThisAccount.get(0).Start_Date__c.daysBetween(c.Start_Date__c); 
    }
}

update newCaseList;// (If not a before trigger)
```

Comment: `casesForThisAccount != null` is not necessary. A query never returns a null list.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox. I just read your article on that topic and learned something.

Comment: thanks Manjit and SFDCFOX.it helps